How can I write to an .INI config file without loading the entire file first
I am trying to write to a .ini file without having to load the entire file first. It seems like a waste of CPU to load a INI file just to make a small change and write the entire file out again. Should I not be so picky and just load the entire file?
I looked at ConfigObj module and I didn't see anything about saving just part of a .ini file to a bigger .ini file. I have so far been using ConfigParser to load the entire file and save it out to disk just to make a small change. My config files are not too large at all, yet. But soon I will need 16KB (section, item) value sizes. I could just put each 8b piece of data in to its own (section) item but then I would need 3 thousand items in just one section with multiple sections with the same amount of items (2-3000) items with short values. Or a few very large items values. You see why I don't want to load every .ini file before writing a small change. I will settle for just the best INI config file parser available. Type validation is not important. Easy to use is important. I don't like those config file parsers that use Dict(conf_item=List(Unicode())) or whatever the heck those config files do. I don't like it and I don't need it.

Maybe you need several ini files, or a database.

INI files are not random access.  The same is true of, for example, JSON.  To tweak it, you need to load the whole file, and write out the modified data.  If you have thousands of configuration items, perhaps SQLite would be a better choice.

@Andrew Morton I think you are right about me needing more than one ini file if I have thousands upon thousands of items in each INI file.
